# vGet как узнать размер видео

Tags: java, youtube

Как узнать размер видео при работе с vGet библиотекой ? Мне надо скачивать видео в моем приложении и мониторить сколько осталось до конца загрузки, скорость скачивания я уже вычислил, теперь же надо размер видео узнать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Кто в теме вот код:

```
public String getSizeVideo(VGet v, DownloadInfo downloadInfo) {
    downloadInfo = v.getVideo().getInfo().get(0);      
    return getFileSizeMegaBytes(downloadInfo.getLength()));
}

private String getFileSizeMegaBytes(long length) {
    return (double) length/(1024*1024)+" mb";
}
```